# Count from a list the number of values in a key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have one dictionary with keys and a list as a value. I want to create a new dictionary which will store the KEY of my_dict but as a value the count of letters that correlate with my_list. If KEY 'A' has 'A', 'B' then I want to count if I find the amount of 'A' or 'B' in my_list.

Also I would like to know how to do it in vanilla Python using nested for loops because I've seen people use:

```
new_dict = [my_dict[x] for x in my_list if x in my_dict]
```

Which I don't really understand fully. I hope I expressed myself correctly.

```
my_dict = {'A': ['A', 'B'], 'B': ['C', 'D'], 'C': ['E', 'F']}
my_list = ['A', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'F', 'F']
new_dict = {}
```

**Output:
**

```
{'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 2}
```

Since key 'A' had as a value 'A', 'B' there was only two A's in my_list but no B's so the count is 2 and that's the value in case of confusion.

```
new_dict = [my_dict[x] for x in my_list if x in my_dict]
```

And I tried to nested for loops but I struggle with nested for loops

Comment: *"one dictionary with one key and multiple values"* - Just to clarify, you mean "a dictionary where each value is a list", right? Cause `my_dict` has three keys, and a dict item can't have multiple values, strictly speaking.

Comment: @wjandrea Yes you are right, the value is a list and I want to count from my_list the amount of letters that correlate to that list. I'll update my question and apologies If I was not clear.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternate solution to the `Counter` solution and the nested for loop above that avoids using libraries but is slightly more efficient than the solution you posted. This solution improves time performance by using a dictionary as an intermediate data structure, which comes with the tradeoff that you have to use additional memory for that dictionary to be more efficient time-wise (depends which is more important to you). And obviously this is more verbose.

```
def count_nested_values(my_dict: dict, my_list: list):
    counts = {}
    for list_val in my_list:
        if list_val in counts:
            counts[list_val] += 1
        else:
            counts[list_val] = 1

    new_dict = {}
    for k, dict_val in my_dict.items():
        new_dict[k] = 0

        # the following loop could be shortened to this line with
        # list comprehension, a ternary, and sum()
        # new_dict[k] = sum(counts[v] if v in counts else 0 for v in dict_val)
        for list_val in dict_val:
            if list_val in counts:
                new_dict[k] += counts[list_val]

    return new_dict
```

I should note that this is basically the same as wjandrea's solution above, just replacing the `Counter` library and dictionary comprehension with the intermediate dictionary and a for loop, respectively.

Why is this beneficial?

In your solution, you are calling the loop `for element in my_list` for each key in `my_dict`, which means that you are reprocessing those values a bunch of times you don't need to. Additionally, for lists in Python, [the `in` operator has O(n) performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46519854/22486304). It is O(1) for dictionaries and sets but lists are more expensive. So when you're calling `element in values`, you're reprocessing each `values` list for every element in `my_list`.

Overall, this is going to lead to O(n^3) performance, which is generally not desirable. The scaling factors are

1. outer loop: number of keys in `my_dict`
2. inner loop: number of values in `my_list`
3. `in` expression in the `if` block: number of values in the nested list (size will vary for each key-value pair in `my_dict`, so it will scale with whatever the largest value list is)

So overall you will have `(keys in my_dict) * (values in my_list) * (values in nested lists)` iterations. In the example input, it's 3 * 6 * 2 = 36 iterations.

The `Counter` solution and my solution above improve performance by using the following algorithm:

1. Preprocess `my_list` to count the occurrences of each value in `my_list` -> the `Counter` object or the first for loop that builds the plain `counts` dictionary. Since dictionary reads and writes are constant time or O(1), the cost of this preprocessing is O(n) where n is the size of `my_list`.
2. Iterate over the key-value pairs in `my_dict` via `my_dict.items()` -> the dictionary comprehension iterable in the `Counter` solution and the second for loop in mine. The cost of that iteration is O(n) where n is the number of keys in `my_dict`, so overall, our solution is now at O(n) where n is either the size of `my_list` and or the number of keys in `my_dict`, whichever is larger.
3. For each key-value pair in `my_dict`, iterate over the nested list value -> input to `sum()` in the `Counter` solution and the nested for loop within the second for loop in mine. This means that overall, the number of iterations of the second for loop including the nested for loop is now the number of *nested values* in `my_dict`. So now our algorithm's overall performance is O(n) where n is either the size of `my_list` and or the number of nested values in `my_dict`, whichever is larger.
4. Have to look up the nested value in `counts` to avoid a `KeyError`. Because `counts` is a dictionary, lookup is O(1), so doesn't hurt.

So the final performance is O(n) as opposed to O(n^3).

tl;dr if you don't care about the time efficiency of your solution – like if you know the input is never going to be large – your solution is correct and will get the job done. But if you care about performance for your solution or for educational purposes, this implementation will be somewhat more efficient, and it also shows roughly what the `Counter` solution does under the hood (there are likely some further optimizations there though).

Comment: You can further simplify `counts[v] if v in counts else 0` to `counts.get(v, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to get the counts beforehand. This saves you having to count each element each loop; all you have to do is look up the count.

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(my_list)

new_dict = {k: sum(counts[e] for e in v) for k,v in my_dict.items()}
```

Result:

```
{'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 2}
```

Comment: Thank you and I understand the answer but I would like to now how to do it the vanilla way, which probably is using nested for loops an that's were I struggle If I practice with the question I posted.

Comment: @dan What do you mean by "vanilla"? `collections` is in the standard library, so it's included in most Python installs, so I would consider it "vanilla Python", as opposed, to say, Pandas, which is a 3rd-party library with its own idioms.

Answer (score 0):

**Using nested loops and a count variable:**

```
for key, values in my_dict.items():
    count = 0
    for element in my_list:
        if element in values:
            count += 1
    new_dict[key] = count
```

Comment: If you want to shorten it: `count = sum(element in values for element in my_list)`. This works because `True == 1` and `False == 0`.